# How to retrieve the parentId of an element created by a previous function?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I'm trying to build a small React.js clone,

In the code snippet below, i made a simple component tree with a succession of functional components

```
function Text(props) {
  return createElement('p', null, props.content)
}

function Hello(props) {
  return createElement(Text, props.content, null)
}

function Home() { // this is the root element
  return createElement('div', null, 
    createElement(Hello, {content: "hello world 1"}, null),
    createElement(Hello, {content: "hello world 2"}, null)
  )
}
```

The createElement function checks the type of the current node, assigning it an id and pushes it into the `data` Array. But to reconstitute the component tree, i need to get the parentId of each components that have been pushed into data.

I assume that if the value of `i` is zero, it means that the current element is the root element. But if not, how to find the `id` of the parent who created the current element ?

```
const data = [];
let i = 0;

function createElement(node, props, children) {
  if(typeof node === "string") {
    data.push({ name: node, id: i, parentId: i > 0 ? i : null });
    i++;
  };
  
  if(typeof node === "function") {
    let functionalComponent = constructFunctionComponent(node);
    data.push({ name: node.name, id: i, parentId: i > 0 ? i : null });
    i++;
    createElement(functionalComponent(props)());
  };
}

function constructFunctionComponent(fc) {
  return (props) => (children) => fc(props, children);
}
```

Here is what a console.log displays if we execute the `Home()` function.
Here the `parentId` keys are obviously all false (except the first one because it is the root element)

```
// current output :
// note that here the parentId keys of each index are not correct (this is what i'm trying to resolve)
[
  { name: 'Home', id: 0, parentId: null },
  { name: 'Hello', id: 1, parentId: 1 },
  { name: 'Text', id: 2, parentId: 2 },
  { name: 'p', id: 3, parentId: 3 },
  { name: 'Hello', id: 4, parentId: 4 },
  { name: 'Text', id: 5, parentId: 5 },
  { name: 'p', id: 6, parentId: 6 },
  { name: 'div', id: 7, parentId: 7 }
]

// expected output:
// here, each parentId keys is a "reference" to the parent that added the index to the array
[
  { name: 'Home', id: 0, parentId: null },
  { name: 'Hello', id: 1, parentId: 7 },
  { name: 'Text', id: 2, parentId: 1 },
  { name: 'p', id: 3, parentId: 2 },
  { name: 'Hello', id: 4, parentId: 7 },
  { name: 'Text', id: 5, parentId: 4 },
  { name: 'p', id: 6, parentId: 5 },
  { name: 'div', id: 7, parentId: 0 }
]
```

I made a codeSandbox which contains the code. Any help would be greatly appreciated !

[Here is a link to the codeSandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-curie-coxo9?file=/src/index.js)

Thanks,

Comment: You do seem to be including the parentId as part of the data element, so can you please clarify what the problem is? What, exactly, do you mean by "reconstitute the component tree"?

Comment: In fact, reconstitute the component tree is the next step. For now i would like to create a simple array of "components" (data) which each element contains a reference to his parent, the parentId key. Here the parentId key is set manually (for the exemple) but it should not be. The only case, in the actual output, where the parent id is correct is when the value of i is equal to 0 (because this is the first time the createElement fonction is called). I have updated the question with an expected output to make it more clear

Comment: Forget about that  `data` array. What you really need to look at for constructing a component tree is the `return` values and the `children` your `createElement` function is being passed.

Comment: Actually, i have been trying something like that and it worked pretty good until i ran into another problem : the state management for each components. my goal is to add the possibility to call a `useState` function to set a custom value stored in each components internal state (this state is a key inside each component of the tree). And because of this recursive call of the createElement function another function call is added to the call stack which cause that the state setted via the custom `useState` is not setted to the correct component.

Answer (score 0):

As you're doing it now, the structure is being evaluated from the leaf nodes up, so the parent ID is not known at the time of each element's creation. You'll have to separate the generation of the IDs from the generation of the elements. Here's an example of what I mean (it's not pretty; you can probably come up with a more elegant way to do it):

```
function createElement(node, props, children) {
    if(typeof node === "string") {
      data.push({ name: node, id: props.id, parentId: props.parentId });
    };
    
    if(typeof node === "function") {
      let functionalComponent = constructFunctionComponent(node);
      data.push({ name: node.name, id: props.id, parentId: props.parentId });
      createElement(functionalComponent(props)());
    };
}

function Home() {
    homeId = 0;
    createElement
    (
        'div',
        homeId,
        createElement(Hello, {content: "hello 1", parentId: homeId, id: (hello1Id = ++homeId)}),
        createElement(Hello, {content: "hello 2", parentId: homeId, id: (hello2Id = ++hello1Id)})
    );
}
```

Now the ID is being created as part of the call to **createElement**, so it can be known and used in any further child creation.